# Error [0x8015] (ESP_ERR_MBEDTLS_X509_CRT_PARSE_FAILED) esp32

Tags: mqtt, esp32, esp-idf

good afternoon colleagues, please see if you can give me a light

<sub>example 1</sub>

```
void conect(void) {
    esp_mqtt_client_handle_t mqttClient;
    
    const char *certificate;
            certificate =
                "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
                "MIIDrzCCApegAwIBAgIQCDvgVpBCRrGhdWrJWZHHSjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBh\n"
                "MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3\n"
                "d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMSAwHgYDVQQDExdEaWdpQ2VydCBHbG9iYWwgUm9vdCBD\n"
                "QTAeFw0wNjExMTAwMDAwMDBaFw0zMTExMTAwMDAwMDBaMGExCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT\n"
                "MRUwEwYDVQQKEwxEaWdpQ2VydCBJbmMxGTAXBgNVBAsTEHd3dy5kaWdpY2VydC5j\n"
                "b20xIDAeBgNVBAMTF0RpZ2lDZXJ0IEdsb2JhbCBSb290IENBMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG\n"
                "9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA4jvhEXLeqKTTo1eqUKKPC3eQyaKl7hLOllsB\n"
                "CSDMAZOnTjC3U/dDxGkAV53ijSLdhwZAAIEJzs4bg7/fzTtxRuLWZscFs3YnFo97\n"
                "nh6Vfe63SKMI2tavegw5BmV/Sl0fvBf4q77uKNd0f3p4mVmFaG5cIzJLv07A6Fpt\n"
                "43C/dxC//AH2hdmoRBBYMql1GNXRor5H4idq9Joz+EkIYIvUX7Q6hL+hqkpMfT7P\n"
                "T19sdl6gSzeRntwi5m3OFBqOasv+zbMUZBfHWymeMr/y7vrTC0LUq7dBMtoM1O/4\n"
                "gdW7jVg/tRvoSSiicNoxBN33shbyTApOB6jtSj1etX+jkMOvJwIDAQABo2MwYTAO\n"
                "BgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAYYwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUA95QNVbR\n"
                "TLtm8KPiGxvDl7I90VUwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUA95QNVbRTLtm8KPiGxvDl7I90VUw\n"
                "DQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAMucN6pIExIK+t1EnE9SsPTfrgT1eXkIoyQY/Esr\n"
                "hMAtudXH/vTBH1jLuG2cenTnmCmrEbXjcKChzUyImZOMkXDiqw8cvpOp/2PV5Adg\n"
                "06O/nVsJ8dWO41P0jmP6P6fbtGbfYmbW0W5BjfIttep3Sp+dWOIrWcBAI+0tKIJF\n"
                "PnlUkiaY4IBIqDfv8NZ5YBberOgOzW6sRBc4L0na4UU+Krk2U886UAb3LujEV0ls\n"
                "YSEY1QSteDwsOoBrp+uvFRTp2InBuThs4pFsiv9kuXclVzDAGySj4dzp30d8tbQk\n"
                "CAUw7C29C79Fv1C5qfPrmAESrciIxpg0X40KPMbp1ZWVbd4=\n"
                "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"

    esp_mqtt_client_config_t mqttConfig = {};

    mqttConfig.uri = "mqtts://broker.emqx.io";
    mqttConfig.port = 8883;

    mqttConfig.cert_pem = certificate;

    mqttConfig.username = "";
    mqttConfig.password = "";
    mqttConfig.keepalive = 60;
    mqttConfig.client_id = "test";

    mqttClient = esp_mqtt_client_init(&mqttConfig);

    esp_mqtt_client_start(mqttClient);

}
```

the code above works perfectly but when I change the certificate variable to std::string it gives an error
below is the change and the error

<sub>example 2</sub>

```
void conect(void) {
    esp_mqtt_client_handle_t mqttClient;
    
    std::string certificate;
            certificate =
                "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
                "MIIDrzCCApegAwIBAgIQCDvgVpBCRrGhdWrJWZHHSjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBh\n"
                "MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3\n"
                "d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMSAwHgYDVQQDExdEaWdpQ2VydCBHbG9iYWwgUm9vdCBD\n"
                "QTAeFw0wNjExMTAwMDAwMDBaFw0zMTExMTAwMDAwMDBaMGExCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT\n"
                "MRUwEwYDVQQKEwxEaWdpQ2VydCBJbmMxGTAXBgNVBAsTEHd3dy5kaWdpY2VydC5j\n"
                "b20xIDAeBgNVBAMTF0RpZ2lDZXJ0IEdsb2JhbCBSb290IENBMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG\n"
                "9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA4jvhEXLeqKTTo1eqUKKPC3eQyaKl7hLOllsB\n"
                "CSDMAZOnTjC3U/dDxGkAV53ijSLdhwZAAIEJzs4bg7/fzTtxRuLWZscFs3YnFo97\n"
                "nh6Vfe63SKMI2tavegw5BmV/Sl0fvBf4q77uKNd0f3p4mVmFaG5cIzJLv07A6Fpt\n"
                "43C/dxC//AH2hdmoRBBYMql1GNXRor5H4idq9Joz+EkIYIvUX7Q6hL+hqkpMfT7P\n"
                "T19sdl6gSzeRntwi5m3OFBqOasv+zbMUZBfHWymeMr/y7vrTC0LUq7dBMtoM1O/4\n"
                "gdW7jVg/tRvoSSiicNoxBN33shbyTApOB6jtSj1etX+jkMOvJwIDAQABo2MwYTAO\n"
                "BgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAYYwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUA95QNVbR\n"
                "TLtm8KPiGxvDl7I90VUwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUA95QNVbRTLtm8KPiGxvDl7I90VUw\n"
                "DQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAMucN6pIExIK+t1EnE9SsPTfrgT1eXkIoyQY/Esr\n"
                "hMAtudXH/vTBH1jLuG2cenTnmCmrEbXjcKChzUyImZOMkXDiqw8cvpOp/2PV5Adg\n"
                "06O/nVsJ8dWO41P0jmP6P6fbtGbfYmbW0W5BjfIttep3Sp+dWOIrWcBAI+0tKIJF\n"
                "PnlUkiaY4IBIqDfv8NZ5YBberOgOzW6sRBc4L0na4UU+Krk2U886UAb3LujEV0ls\n"
                "YSEY1QSteDwsOoBrp+uvFRTp2InBuThs4pFsiv9kuXclVzDAGySj4dzp30d8tbQk\n"
                "CAUw7C29C79Fv1C5qfPrmAESrciIxpg0X40KPMbp1ZWVbd4=\n"
                "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"

    esp_mqtt_client_config_t mqttConfig = {};

    mqttConfig.uri = "mqtts://broker.emqx.io";
    mqttConfig.port = 8883;

    mqttConfig.cert_pem = certificate.c_str();
    
    mqttConfig.username = "";
    mqttConfig.password = "";
    mqttConfig.keepalive = 60;
    mqttConfig.client_id = "test";

    mqttClient = esp_mqtt_client_init(&mqttConfig);

    esp_mqtt_client_start(mqttClient);

}
```

when this certificate variable is set to std::string it gives an error:
**E (5021) esp-tls-mbedtls: mbedtls_x509_crt_parse returned -0x2180
E (5021) esp-tls-mbedtls: Failed to set client configurations, returned [0x8015] (ESP_ERR_MBEDTLS_X509_CRT_PARSE_FAILED)
E (5031) esp-tls: create_ssl_handle failed
E (5031) esp-tls: Failed to open new connection
E (5041) TRANSPORT_BASE: Failed to open a new connection
E (5051) MQTT_CLIENT: Error transport connect**

**mqttConfig.cert_pem** accepts const char * but converting a string variable gives the above error and if I create the variable as const char * it works as per example 1
can someone please guide me what could be going on

```
const char *p = certificate.c_str();
mqttConfig.cert_pem = p;
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Which version are you using ? Shouldn't you use the struct esp_mqtt_client_config_t::broker_t::verification_t struct and its attribute certificate ?

Comment: I am using idf version: v4.4
this is the structure I'm just not understanding because if I put const char * it works and if I put string it doesn't work, it gives the error.
I've compared character by character and they are all the same

Comment: I thought you were using the latest version of the espressif framework. Indeed, we have cert_perm in 4.4.
What kind of certificate are you using ? A PEM-format must have a terminating NULL-character, while a DER-format certificate requires the length to be passed in cert_len.
Have you tried checking that ?

Comment: Good morning, I'm using version 4.4, I didn't install version 5.
I already put in the PEM format the NULL character (\0) I already put (\n) and nothing worked.
While DER I already passed the length in mqttConfig.cert_len

What makes me intrigued is that if I create a variable const char* with the certificate it works perfectly.
If I create a variable like std::string with the certificate it generates the above error.
I can't understand why